# Mongoose and BlueBird return from promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bluebird

I use mongoose and bluebird as a promise framework.
Everytime I use "save" or "remove"  I get this error :

```
Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it
```

I really tried spending on it a few days, while googling, I tried so much ways, to mention some:

1. Creating a promise and resolve it in save/remove CB;
2. putting 'return' in so many logical combinations to make sure it
   always 'return' from a promise.
3. Creating functions in the model, and naming it "saveAsync" (I saw it
   in one example) and there doing all the promise handling.
4. Kinda funny but I tried updating all my project npm packages,
   because I saw talks about it in github and someone mentioned they
   solved it already. but it didn't work.

   And much more.. I'm really desperate.
   Don't get me wrong, the code works great, but seeing this HUGE warnings in my console each time makes me feel really guilty.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This error means some code did something like:

```
somePromise.then(x => {
    someOtherPromiseReturningFunction();
}).then(value => {
   // forgot a return, oh dear
});
```

Which is a very common mistake of forgetting a `return`, it messes with error handling and causes issues.

Sometimes the problem is not with *your* code but with the code of a library you're using - in that case you should disable warnings for that code:

- Require bluebird separately for your own code and for mongoose via `require("bluebird")` and use it with warnings.
- Disable warnings for the copy mongoose uses.

You can get two copies of bluebird by using `require("bluebird")` in your code and overriding mongoose's Promise with `require("bluebird/js/release/promise")();` which creates a standalone copy.

Comment: Until now my mongoose has been required in that way:  `import mongoose     from 'mongoose';
    mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');`  Isn't it the same? and currently it doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't it the same require you did basically? Can I turn the warnings to that? (Sorry about double comment, too late to edit).